# In the code in nav tag there is dropdown but the drop menu is not appearing?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

**CODE:**

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Admin Panel</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Pratham Pande
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?user_profile">Profile</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?view_products">Products</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?view_customers">Customers</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?pro_cat">Product Categories</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

In this the dropdown is not working. The dropdown menu options are not appearing.  The title is appearing on the page but after clicking it dropdown options are not coming.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: you need to add css

Comment: @nourza some java script too might help